# How do I stretch the middle <div> height in a three-<div> layout?

Tags: css, layout, html

I am trying to do is to layout three `<div>`s: a top (for navigation), center, and footer `<div>`. 
The top and bottom `<div>`s have fixed height.

How can I make the center `<div>` stretch 100% and subtract the height of the others (top and bottom)?

Note: I have given the body, html height 100%.

Answer (score 0):

if it's divs you're using, I think that Javascript is the only answer to this one.